How to test Webfilter in WebTestClient
I am using a custom filter
@Component
class WebFilter(private service1: Service) : WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val webStateMono= CheckStateMonoStatus(
            service1::getServiceDetails
        )

    return webStateMono.flatMap { state ->
        chain.filter(exchange)
            .contextWrite { state ->
                content.put("service1Available", state)
            }
    }
}

    private fun CheckStateMonoStatus(vararg services: suspend () -> Any?): Mono<Boolean> {
        val service = services.map { services ->
            mono { service()}
        }
        return Mono.zipDelayError(service) { response ->
            response.any { it!=null }
        }.onErrorReturn(false)
    }
    }

I am trying to write controller layer test case for my API where this service is being used. But I am not able to get the test case running. Is there a way to add this custom filter as an parameter in WebTestClient
